# Really big struggle getting iconv gem installed on Mac OS X 10.6.4

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, iconv

This is a real hassle. Here is the output from the struggle:

```
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no
```

My command line is:

```
sudo gem install iconv
```

"which iconv" yields:

```
/opt/local/bin/iconv
```

I really don't even know what those "checking for" lines mean up there. Why on EARTH would iconv() not be present in iconv.h? Makes no sense to me. iconv.h lives in /opt/local/include.

EDIT:

Here is the output from mkmf.log:

```
    have_func: checking for iconv() in iconv.h... -------------------- no

    "gcc -o conftest -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I. -I/opt/local/bin/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L/opt/local/bin/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64      -lruby  -lpthread -ldl  "
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_libiconv", referenced from:
          _libiconv$non_lazy_ptr in ccF0PUYQ.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_libiconv", referenced from:
          _t in cc0k5gYm.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc3Rrwkf.out (No such file or directory)
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include <iconv.h>
    2: 
    3: /*top*/
    4: int main() { return 0; }
    5: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))iconv; return 0; }
    /* end */

    "gcc -o conftest -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I. -I/opt/local/bin/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L/opt/local/bin/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64      -lruby  -lpthread -ldl  "
    conftest.c: In function 't':
    conftest.c:5: error: too few arguments to function 'libiconv'
    conftest.c: In function 't':
    conftest.c:5: error: too few arguments to function 'libiconv'
    lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccfQKL4Y.out
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include <iconv.h>
    2: 
    3: /*top*/
    4: int main() { return 0; }
    5: int t() { iconv(); return 0; }
    /* end */

    --------------------

    have_library: checking for iconv() in -liconv... -------------------- no

    "gcc -o conftest -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I. -I/opt/local/bin/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L/opt/local/bin/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64      -lruby -liconv  -lpthread -ldl  "
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_libiconv", referenced from:
          _t in ccorhTF7.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccqa9vmd.out (No such file or directory)
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include <iconv.h>
    2: 
    3: /*top*/
    4: int main() { return 0; }
    5: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))iconv; return 0; }
    /* end */

    "gcc -o conftest -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I. -I/opt/local/bin/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L/opt/local/bin/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64      -lruby -liconv  -lpthread -ldl  "
    conftest.c: In function 't':
    conftest.c:5: error: too few arguments to function 'libiconv'
    conftest.c: In function 't':
    conftest.c:5: error: too few arguments to function 'libiconv'
    lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//cc2UrCWJ.out
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include <iconv.h>
    2: 
    3: /*top*/
    4: int main() { return 0; }
    5: int t() { iconv(); return 0; }
    /* end */

    --------------------
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Paste the part of config.log where it's checking (by trying to compile a program); you may find the check is broken.

Comment: Done Nicholas, looks like you are right. Looks like I might have a bad libiconv? I installed it using MacPorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the weirdest thing. When I go to the gem directory and do:

```
ruby extconf.rb
```

and:

```
make
```

and:

```
make install
```

then:

sudo gem install iconv

it works! I just don't know why it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error as well, on OS X 10.9.1. My solution was to reinstall libiconv, which was installed with homebrew.